# Match type in a list of type using C++ template

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I need to match a type in a list of types at compile time using C++ template. Here is my code but it compiles to an error. Any idea how i can fix it?

```
template <typename T, typename X, typename... Rs>
struct match
{
    using test = typename std::conditional<std::is_same<T, X>::value, X, bool>::type;
    using more = typename match<T, Rs...>::type;
    using type = typename std::conditional<std::is_same<test, bool>::value, more, test>::type;
};

template <typename T>
struct match<T, bool>
{
    using type = bool;
};

match<int, int, float>::type x;
```

The error is:

```
1.cpp:99:45: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be at least 2)
  using more = typename match<T, Rs...>::type;

                                         ^
```

Comment: What do you expect `match<int, int, float>::type` to evaluate to? What's the reason for your expectation?

Comment: I expect it to be `int`. And i expect `match<int, double, float>::type` to be `bool` (because `int` doesn't match any of `double, float`)

Comment: I'm guessing that i will need to use `std::tuple_element` to traverse all target types...

Comment: @cow you noticed you're defining `type` and `more` in terms of each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a partial specialization to handle the case with exactly two template arguments, otherwise the instantiation of `more` will result in the instantiation of `match` with one template argument, thus an error occurs. Your `match<T, bool>` only handles the case where the last argument is `bool`, you should declare it as, for example,

```
template <typename T, typename X>
struct match<T, X>
{
    using type = typename std::conditional<std::is_same<T, X>::value, X, bool>::type;
};
```

---

In addition, I don't know what is the use of `test`. I think using `more` directly in the definition of `type` is sufficient:

```
template <typename T, typename X, typename... Rs>
struct match
{
    using more = typename match<T, Rs...>::type;
    using type = typename std::conditional<std::is_same<T, X>::value, X, more>::type;
};
```

This is still not the best solution, because it will result in the instantiation of `more` even if `T` matches `X` (in this case we can assert `match::type` is `X` without the instantiation of `more`). To avoid the unnecessary instantiation, you can add an additional partial specialization:

```
template <typename T, typename... Rs>
struct match<T, T, Rs...>
{
    using type = T;
};
```

With this partial specialization, the primary template only matches the case where `T` is not `X`, thus you can further simplify the primary template as

```
template <typename T, typename X, typename... Rs>
struct match
{
    using type = typename match<T, Rs...>::type;
};
```

For completeness, the final solution would be:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename X, typename... Rs>
struct match
{
    using type = typename match<T, Rs...>::type;
};

template <typename T, typename... Rs>
struct match<T, T, Rs...>
{
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T, typename X>
struct match<T, X>
{
    using type = typename std::conditional<std::is_same<T, X>::value, X, bool>::type;
};

static_assert(std::is_same<int, match<int, int, float>::type>::value);
```

Comment: However, using the final solution above, a `match<int, int>` will result in compiler error `ambiguous partial specializations`. So it requires at least 3 template params. To fix this, you may replace the 2nd struct definition `template <typename T, typename... Rs> struct Match<T, T, Rs...>` with `template <typename T, typename X, typename... Rs> struct Match<T, T, X, Rs...>`